# Let $f: N \rightarrow R$ be a function $f(n) = \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}} \rfloor$ prove that $f(n) \in \Theta (n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

> Let $f: N \rightarrow R$ be a function $f(n) = \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}} \rfloor$. Prove that $f(n) \in \Theta (n)$

I came across this problem and honestly have no idea where to start.

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be a member of $\Theta(n)$?

Comment: I know that it means that $f(n) \in O(n)$ and $f(n) \in \Omega (n)$ but how do I prove that

Comment: Asymptotically the floor function doesn't do anything, so $f(n)$ behaves like $n/2$, which is clearly both $O(n)$ and $\Omega(n)$. You have that $|f(x) - x/2| \le 1$ always, so I'm not sure what else you need to show. If you have a formal definition of $\Omega(n)$ that you prefer that would help this question.

Comment: So what does it mean for $f \in O(n)$, for example?  What’s the definition?

Comment: @desiigner can you elaborate with some kind of statement / proof on why the asymptotically the floor function doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

For large enough $n$,
$\dfrac{n}{3}
\lt f(n)
\le \dfrac{n}{2}
$.

This should be enough.